# SMTP server force outbound traffic

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, email, domain-controller, smtp

I'm having some trouble with setting up a SMTP server on a windows server 2003 machine, while trying to send emails using PHP through the internet, but to domain email addresses.

**Common info:**

- I'm a newbie on this, so I don't know many of the concepts
- Machine has Windows Server 2003 Server
- Machine on a domain (mydomain.com)
- Machine is not a domain controller
- Machine accesses a domain controller through the internet (WAN with a corporate VPN link by the internet provider setup on the machine's gateway - adsl modem/router)
- Email addresses use the same suffix (mydomain.com)
- Do not have access to domain controller configuration

**First Scenario**

- TCP/IP DNS: 1st 192.168.200.xxx   2nd 8.8.8.8
- Direct access to domain controller is functional
- PHP mail using localhost to a user@mydomain.com won't work, because the remote mail server rejects emails from internal traffic (apparently!?!)  (internal DNS)

**Second Scenario**

- TCP/IP DNS: 1st  8.8.8.8   2nd 192.168.200.xxx   (**switched**)
- Direct access to domain controller is **not** functional, only local accounts work
- PHP mail using localhost to a user@mydomain.com **does** work, because the remote mail server is accessed through its internet/external address (ISP DNS).

So, what I needed is to have both (1) access to the domain controller and (2) PHP mail using localhost to a user@mydomain.com account working.

Any pointers? Thanks in advance

edit: initally posted at stackoverflow but changed it here after recommendation.